# saving generated pdf in public file using Barryvdh\Snappy package

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I tried to save the generated pdf in public folder using laravel 5.2 but it is not working, below is my code:

```
$path = base_path('public/uploads/files/');
$pdf_name = time().'.pdf';
PDF::loadView('pdf.pdf', [ 'data' => $data ])->save($path.$pdf_name);
```

This is the error I got:

> FatalErrorException in WindowsPipes.php line 137:
>   Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Comment: what is your view name is it `pdf.blade.php` inside `pdf` folder inside `views` folder ?

Comment: can you post your pdf.blade.php view?

Comment: the view is pdf.blade.php in view folder pdf subfolder :                               ```<table border="1" width="600px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">

    <tr>
            <td width="300px" style="vertical-align: top; line-height: 0.5px; padding-left: 3px;">
                </br>
                <h3>Details</h3></br>
                <h4>Email: {{$data ['email'] }}</h4></br>
                <h4>Amount: {{$data ['amount']}}</h4></br>
                 </td>
    </tr>

</table>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this issue: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/129

To solve this, set the timeout to 3600 in your `config/snappy.php` file like so:

```
'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary' => base_path('vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64'),
        'timeout' => 3600,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
```